# Timeshift broke my OS

Tags: grub2, backup, elementary-os, system-recovery

I am a linux noob who is using Elementary OS. Recently I had to reinstall my OS in order to get the new version of elementary OS (Odin).
I had a backup of my file made using deja dups (that I've recovered without any issue) and a backup of the system made with Timeshift.
What happened is that, after having reinstalled Timeshift and told him to recover the last version of my system (all using timeshift default option which I thought were legit) the OS just stopped to work. After the reboot in fact the only thing I could see was a minimal terminal exactly like this one [image]

I tried to use boot reipair but it didn't worked (it just failed to repair anything).

I had to access the boot menu and boot with windows, now I just reinstalled Elementary OS but i still didn't recovered the system using timeshift and I am afraid the issue will happen again. Also I am very curious about what happened and it seems a good way to learn new things about how linux works.
Thank to whoever is going to help me!

Comment: What exactly were you trying to recover? What files were being backed up by this timeshift thing? If you have installed a new version of your system (which is what you say you did), why are you trying to go back to the old version?

Comment: I thought the purpose of timeshift was to recover, for example, the installed application with their own old preferences ecc. I misconceived the purpose of a system backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly the only way to upgrade from Elementary 5 to 6 is - at least at this point of time - to uninstall old and install new. That's an odd one out in Linux world.

---

You describe that you made a system backup with Timeshift, then installed a new OS version, then installed Timeshift and tried to do a system restore from a backup you created with *previous version*... From Timeshift's [Github page](https://github.com/teejee2008/timeshift#readme):

"Timeshift for Linux is an application that provides functionality similar to the System Restore feature in Windows"

What do you think, would you be able to do a successful system restore on Win10 using system backup from Win7?

Your system boots to grub, and a knowledgeable user can get his system running from here. However because you tried to restore incorrectly, your system is most likely at this point hopelessly mangled with incorrect / incompatible libraries etc. It'd probably be possible to unknot it and as a learning experience it might be even fun... but you need a certain amount of not-so-basic understanding of Linux to figure out how to even start.

For a new user, the only sensible option (in my opinion) is just wipe the disk, then install the current version of the OS and any applications you use. It might be possible to restore your preferences from the old backup, but I wouldn't bother; unless, again, learning experience etc. Just reconfiguring things is a lot easier and faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought that Timeshift was able to just restore app and preferences without affecting libraries necessary for the new OS to properly work. Anyway, as far as I know, the only way to make the update from Elementary  5 to elementary  6 is to fully reinstall the OS (I know that normally it doesn't work this way). I've already proceeded to wipe the disk and reinstall the OS, I just wanted to know if it was possible to recover app and preferences but if it is not a basic operation maybe i'd better study more before trying. Anyway thank you again for the clarifications!

Comment: By Gum you're right! My apology; and I've updated the answer accordingly. In general that's exactly what all system backup/restore utilities are for; restoring the system from backup in case of a catastrophic failure so that you don't have to reinstall/reconfigure everything. But they never work across major upgrades, simply too much changes. I've not tested (fingers crossed!) but I'd expect restores over minor upgrades work correctly. For example you now create a backup with 6.0 I'd be surprised if you had a problem doing a restore on 6.1 - but I can't be certain.

Comment: Personally I tend to backup my preferences separately on a USB stick. Of course major application version upgrades also cause some changes in preferences, but since they're just text files it's possible - if not always easy :-D - to update them manually :-)

Comment: Ok, now I perfectly got what I did wrong. thank you again!